# Azure Marketplace deploy programmatically from PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I am trying to deploy netscalervpx-120 from the Marketplace programmatically. When I go to the Marketplace > Select Citrix ADC12.1 and choose the option "Want to deploy programmatically? Get started" by default the Subscription Status button is Disable.

I executed the command to accept the licensing terms:
(Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher Citrix -Product netscalervpx-120 -name netscalerbyol | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept).

Yet, I am still trying to figure out how to Enable the button/option from PowerShell. Is this possible? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzq27.jpg)

Comment: Is this happening with out any errors?

Comment: I have a runbook that deploys the VM’s programmatically, yet, I am working on fully automating the deployment (i.e., create new subscription, **enabling the option from the Marketplace reported in this case**, and last execute the runbook). The only missing piece is to enable the option from the Marketplace. I’ve searched around and can’t find the PowerShell cmdlet to enable the setting.